# ¿Cómo capturo las variables de un formulario para mostrarlas después en un correo (Codeigniter)?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

Quiero enviar un email con `CI_codeigniter` pero no puedo capturar las variables input en  $this->email->message para que las muestre como html cuando la envie.

Controlador:

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Emails extends CI_Controller {
function index(){

$this->load->view('contacto/mailcontacto', $datos); 
}
function enviar() {
//Descargar la libreria
$this->load->library('email'); 

        $nombre = $this->input->post('nombre');
        $telefono = $this->input->post('telefono');
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $asunto = $this->input->post('asunto');
        $mensaje = $this->input->post('mensaje');
        $email_body ="<div>hello world</div>";

    // Datos para enviar el correo
        $this->email->from('correo@correo.com', 'Contacto');
        $this->email->to('correo@correo.com');
        $this->email->subject($asunto);               
        $this->email->message('');


        $this->email->send();
        redirect('contacto');
}


   }
?>
```

Config:

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
$config = array();
$config['useragent'] = "CodeIgniter"; // or "/usr/sbin/sendmail"
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$config['smtp_host']    = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
$config['smtp_port'] = 465;
$config['smtp_user'] = 'correo@correo.com'; // correo sin espacio
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'contrasena';
$config['smtp_timeout'] = '7';
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
$config['mailtype'] = 'text'; // or html
$config['validation'] = TRUE; // bool whether to validate email or not
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
$config['crlf']    = "\n";

?>
```

View:

```
<form action="emails/enviar" method="post">

<table style="width:80%; margin-left:12%">
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td><table style="width:70%; margin-left:16%; margin-right:16%">
 <tbody>
 <tr>
  <td><label><a >Nombre:</a></label></td>

 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td ><input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre"   >     </td>

 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td >Telefono:</a></label></td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="text"  id="telefono"      name="telefono" ></td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td ><label><a>Email:</a></label></td>

</tr>

<tr>
  <td><input type="text"  id="email" name="email"></td>

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
    <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
  <td><table style="width:100%">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Asunto:</a></label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text"  id="asunto"  name="asunto" ></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label><a >Mensaje:</a></label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>

<td><textarea rows="04" id="mensaje" name="mensaje" ></textarea>       </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table style="width:100%; background:#ffffff;">
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td><button   type="submit" value="enviar"  >Enviar</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>

</table>
```

!Solución!:

```
$nombre = $this->input->post('nombre');
        $telefono = $this->input->post('telefono');
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $asunto = $this->input->post('asunto');
        $mensaje = $this->input->post('mensaje');
        $body_msg =  '<html><body><br />'.
'<h2><font face="times new roman" color="#da0021"><span><font face="times    new roman" color="#00769f"> CONTACTO VIAJANDOFACIL.COM</h2></font>'.
"<tr><td><strong>Nombre</strong> </td><td>" . $nombre . "</td></tr>".

"<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>" . $telefono . "</td></tr>".

  "<tr><td><strong>Telefono:</strong> </td><td>" . $email. "</td></tr>".

   "<tr><td><strong>Asunto:</strong> </td><td>" . $asunto . "</td></tr>".


   "<tr><td><strong>Comentario:</strong> </td><td>" . $mensaje . "</td></tr>".

    '<tr><td><img src="http://www.viajandofacil.com/logo.png"/></td></tr>'.

"<br />";
```

Comment: Coloca el código html de tu vista para tener una mejor idea de lo que estas realizando

Comment: Hola Juan Ya subi la vista del formulario

Comment: Ok, ya lo revisé, ¿cual es el problema que tienes?, quieres enviar el mensaje con etiquetas html para darle formato al contenido del mensaje o que deseas realizar? lo que veo es que dejas $this->email->message(''); de esa manera no estas enviando nada en el cuerpo del mensaje en vez de comillas, deberias poner el texto del mensaje.

Comment: Juan en  $this->email->message(''); habia colocado la variable  $email_body  de esta forma $this->email->message('$email_body'); y al parecer si me lo formateba lo que intento hacer es como capturar las variables input  $nombre = $this->input->post('nombre'); $telefono = $this->input->post('telefono');  etc etc. y a la vez que sea en un formato html estetico para cuando se reciba el correo en cuestion.

Comment: Entonces al momento de llamar $this->input->post('nombre'); no te llega nada del formulario, es decir las variables te quedan sin asignar o si recibes algun valor en ellas?

Comment: Si el captura el formulario lo he probado con subject pero lo que no se es como capturar las otras variables como nombre y enviarla en una plantilla html al correo

Comment: Bueno si ya estas obteniendo el valor de las variables, solo concatena en en un string la plantilla por ejemplo: `$body_msg = "Hola <b>".$nombre."<b/><br/> gracias por el envir el mensaje con asunto: <b>".$asunto."<b/>"` Luego la variable la envias en `$this->email->message($body_msg);` y ya va con formato html.

Comment: Muchas gracias  ya coloque la solución apoyada por Juan saludos

Comment: De nada ya coloque respuesta, si te resulto útil marcala como solución a tu problema, así otros usuarios también pueden encontrarla útil.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39282/discussion-between-ing-alejandro-montes-and-juan-pinzon).

Answer (score 0):

Si las variables ya estan asignadas puedes hacer lo siguiente:

`$body_msg = "Hola <b>".$nombre."<b/><br/> gracias por el envir el mensaje con asunto: <b>".$asunto."<b/>"`

Luego la variable la envias en:

```
$this->email->message($body_msg);
```

y ya va con formato html.